# Selenium webdriver.Chrome() throws WebDriverException when called from docker container. Docker networking issue?

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am on `selenium=4.12.0`. When I import
`from selenium import webdriver`
and later try to download the chrome driver like so:
`webdriver.Chrome()`

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 144, in run
raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}.\n{result}{stderr}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/linux/selenium-manager --browser chrome --output json.
{'code': 65, 'message': 'error sending request for url (https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/117.0.5938.149/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Operation timed out (os error 110)', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}
```

However when I click the link that apparently gets tried by selenium, I can indeed download the driver zip. So I think this  is a docker networking issue?

Any help would be much appreciated.

I searched stackoverflow and Google for a similar error but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this thing:

1. Download stable **chromedriver** (not simple chrome) from [ChromeDriver List](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)
2. Modify your code to this style:

   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

   from selenium import webdriver

   chrome_service = Service(
   "C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver116\chromedriver.exe"
   )

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)

Put path to the downloaded driver inside Service() and everything will work!